# Error in Npm installation

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, npm

I downlaoded Node.js through MSI and when i was doing version check i got no error  on 'node -v' but on 'npm -v' there is a error thrown [Error Outpu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeDjn.png)

Thank you.

Comment: If you install `npmlog` somewhere locally the latest version doesn't reflect the folder structure of the structure in your screenshot. There's no nested module called `lodash._createpadding` for example.

Comment: I recommend uninstalling node, physically removing any remaining folders from your program files/nodejs folder and then reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

Your package.json appears to be invalid. Use a json validator (e.g. http://jsonlint.com/) to find the error.

Comment: So you are saying that i should check json file in npm folder by running it in JSONLint?

Comment: The error pretty clearly states that the error is in "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmlog\node_modules\gauge\node_modules\lodash._createpadding\node_modules\lodash.repeat\package.json".

Answer (score 0):

I think couple of files are missing or package.json is invalid. The easiest solution is to Uninstall the current version and Reinstall node.js globally.

If you want to fix it then try to validate your package.json. once you do that you may be able to find out the problem.

Also did you check whether node is installed properly?

Comment: I tried re-installing but it failed too, and node is working properly.

Comment: can you have a look at this link: https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting